# Singular values of matrix. Estimate norm of the expression

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-norms, singular-values

Let singular values of matrix A are written in vector $s = (s_1, \ldots, s_n)$ in decreasing order ($n \ge 2$). Let $x,y$ are orthogonal vectors with $\|x\| = 1$ and $\|y\| = 1$.

What is the biggest value of $\frac{\|Ax- Ay\|}{\|x-y\|}$?

I know about singular values only from wikipedia page, so I need help.

Maybe we can use spectral theory and then apply min-max theorem $s_1 = \max \lambda_i$. I thought like that:

$$x = \sum x_i e_i, \quad y = \sum y_i e_i$$

where $\{e_i\}_1^n$ is a basis from eigenvectors.

Then
$$Ax - Ay = A(x-y) = A \sum (x_i-y_i) e_i = \sum (x_i-y_i) Ae_i = \sum \lambda_i(x_i-y_i)e_i$$

$$\|Ax-Ay\| = \|\sum \lambda_i(x_i-y_i)e_i\| \le \sum |\lambda_i| |x_i-y_i| \le s_1\sum|x_i-y_i| $$

$$\|x-y\|^2 = \|x\|^2 + \|y\|^2 = 2 \Rightarrow \|x-y\| = \sqrt2$$

$$\frac{\|Ax-Ay\|}{\|x-y\|} \le s_1 \frac{\sum|x_i-y_i|}{\sqrt2}$$

Is it a good way? And if yes, how to end my solution?

Comment: @Hyperplane hmm, actually, ok. And is it significant that x and y are orthogonal?

Comment: It is indeed smaller than the operator norm. Perhaps you could try to use the min-max characterisation of singular values?

Comment: @Alex whoops overlooked that condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you are using Euclidean norm, the largest possible value is $s_1$.

Since $\{x,y\}$ is orthonormal, $x-y=\sqrt{2}u$ for some unit vector $u$. It follows that
$$
\frac{\|Ax-Ay\|}{\|x-y\|}=\frac{\|\sqrt{2}Au\|}{\|\sqrt{2}u\|}=\frac{\|Au\|}{\|u\|}\le\|A\|=s_1
$$
and equality holds when $u$ is a singular vector corresponding to the singular value $s_1$, $x=\sqrt{2}(v+u)$ and $y=\sqrt{2}(v-u)$ for some unit vector $v\perp u$.

**Remark.** Your proof attempt is incorrect. $A$ is not necessarily diagonalisable in the first place. Even if it is diagonalisable, you seem to think that $|\lambda_i|\le s_i$, but this does not survive an obvious sanity check: in case $A$ is nonsingular, since $\prod_i\lambda_i=\det A=\prod_i s_i$, if $|\lambda_i|\le s_i$ for all $i$, we must have $|\lambda_i|=s_i$ for each $i$. But this implies that $\|A\|_F^2=\sum_i|\lambda_i|^2$, which is true only when $A$ is a normal matrix.

Comment: Do we really need that $x,y$ be orthogonal, or even unit norm? Is it not sufficient that $x\neq y$, since we always have $\|Ax-Ay\|=\|A(x-y)\|\leq \|A\|\|x - y\|$?

Comment: @V.S.e.H. We don't need orthogonality to establish $\|Ax-Ay\|\le\|A\|\|x-y\|$. I express the inequality in terms of $u$ simply because its use simplifies the proof of *equality* notationally.

Comment: Thanks for clarification, I'm just a bit puzzled why these conditions are put forward by the OP in the first place. They seem kind of arbitrary.